# Can you add xaml into your FlipTileData BackContent?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, secondary-live-tile

Is it possible to set `xaml` inside the `FlipTileData.BackContent`? Basically I just want to be able to set a full layout with multiple lines, control over spacing and layout and maybe an inline image.
Is this possible or is the `FlipTileData.BackContent` limited to text only?

This is my current code for `BackContent` but I can not get anything other than just text to work in the there.

```
private FlipTileData GetSecondaryTileData()
    {
        FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData
        {
            Title = resortforTile.ListName,
            BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/MountainTile.png", UriKind.Relative),
            BackContent = ""
        };

        return tileData;
    }
```

Comment: This should be text.

Comment: From what I saw in the docs it only accepts a string, so there's no way by default to display content. You could at minimum provide linebreaks though with ascii like dec "line one&#10;line two" or hex "line one&#0a;line two" for a little bit of layout control but not much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set XAML as BackContent but you can render the XAML into an image and set the BackBackgroundImage to this image.

More info at http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/03/advanced-transparent-live-tiles-with-count-for-windows-phone/

Comment: Thank you. This will work great. A lot more coding but at least I will get the results I am looking for.